# Getting node data from a queue in java

Tags: java, pointers, methods, null, queue

I am getting a null pointer exception in my driver from this method that I created to get data from the first node in a queue I don't know where it is going out of bounds.

```
public int getData(){
        Node temp = rear;
        if(rear == null){
            throw new NoSuchElementException("No Data");
        }
        while(temp != null){
            temp = temp.next;
        }
        return temp.data;


    }
```

Comment: What do you think `while(temp != null)` does? Especially if it's then followed by `temp.data`? What is the only possible value of `temp` after the loop?

Comment: Thank you so much I've been working on this for a while (the whole project and I was getting caught up on the little things, such a silly mistake on my part) thank you though much appreciated.

Comment: Try to use an IDE like Eclipse or NetBeans. They have good debugging tools especially helpful for beginners.